# Who is this background character before we re-encounter Thor in Endgame?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-identification, avengers-endgame

Just before we meet Thor in

> New Asgard,

Banner and Rocket meet

> Valkyrie on a pier and discuss Thor's situation.

In the far background, there is a large clothed CGI character, roughly Hulk- or Titan-sized.

[image]

**Who is this CGI character?**

---

Incidentally, it's definitely not

> Korg, as he will be encountered moments later on Thor's couch.

Comment: Why can’t it be Korg, on his way over to Thor’s place for a beer? He knows where he’s going, so he’ll get there well before Banner and Rocket do, and be sitting on the sofa by the time they arrive.

Comment: @MikeScott:.  Because Korg is in the middle of a Fortnite  match.   And it just doesn't look like Korg's built or gait anyhow.  Out of universe, it just wouldn't make sense to spoil the reveal coming up in 30 seconds.

Comment: FWIW, Erik Voss talks about this character in [this Easter Egg video](https://youtu.be/8mI_Txewg2E?t=371), but frankly, he doesn't say much.  He says, "It's not Beta Ray Bill.  It could be some other Sakaar gladiator. "

Answer (score 4):

I believe that the CGI character is a member of the Sakaaran Rebellion, originally led by Korg in *Thor: Ragnarok*. Some members of the rebellion were killed while fighting against the Berserker army on Asgard, while others were killed by Thanos and the Black Order during their attack on the *Statesman*. However, a few survived and settled on Earth to create New Asgard. The audience definitely knows that Korg and Miek survive. Two other possible survivors that we know are Biff and Tasba.

[image]

[image: Biff]

Biff is the character in the lower image. Tasba is the purple character seen in the bottom left of the top image. They do not have confirmed deaths, so it is entirely possible that one of them is the character in the scene. However, Biff appears to be a human in a suit, so it is unlikely that it is him.

Additionally, the character could be the black character with blue paint featured on the right of the top picture, who is clearly computer-generated and fits the stocky build of the character in the scene.

Comment: If you look closely at the structure of the arms, shoulders and head, and the size, I believe the best chance is that it's the black and blue character if it's any of these.

Comment: Do you have any higher resolution? That first image is useless.

Comment: I think it's the character mentioned in your final paragraph but they appear to be unnamed so far.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's a definitive answer to this question. However, I would imagine it is supposed to be the tall, bulky Sakaaran gladiator rebel in the black armour with blue paint. We see them a few times in *Thor: Ragnarok*, for example, when they gather around Loki before making the escape to Asgard.

[image: The Sakaaran gladiator rebels stand around an unseen Loki on the ground]

As far as I'm aware we don't see this character again in *Thor: Ragnarok* though they almost certainly travel to Asgard on the Statesman. As such it is unclear if they survive both Asgard/Hela and Thanos. However, given it is the only character we've seen that resembles the one in question it almost certainly is the same one.

I've checked a few common places for information and can't see a name for this character, so I believe they are indeed just a background unnamed character. They do show up in *Marvel's Thor: Ragnarok - The Art Of The Movie*, however, again they are unnamed and just shown as an example of the Sakaaran gladiators.

[image: Page from the art of book showing concept art for 4 unnamed Sakaaran gladiators]

Answer (score -3):

Looking at the pictures from this article detailing some [Thor Ragnorak concept art,](https://www.syfy.com/syfywire/marvel-studios-concept-artist-miek-thor-ragnarok) it would appear to be Korg's friend and fellow gladiator [Miek.](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Miek)

Here's a photo from the first article

[image: Miek He's an insect who has knives for hands]

Comment: Wasn't Miek in Thor's cabin?

Comment: @Jenayah yes and is a lot smaller than that character

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Wasn't he just not wearing armor?

Comment: @Laurel aye but Miek is still smaller than the character we are trying to identify here

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot What I mean is that Miek was the slug-like creature on the couch with Korg. See [here](https://chicago.suntimes.com/entertainment/avengers-endgame-spoilers-yellow-submarine-big-lebowski-kinks-steppenwolf-traffic-kitty-kallen/) for a mention of this.

Comment: Miek is on Thor's couch immediate after this scene.   It's definitely not Miek.

Comment: Eh, the character in the gif is travelling, and is closer to the rest of town than Hulk & Rocket. It could be a suited-up Miek on his way back to Thor’s house.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite:   It just isn't.   (1) It doesn't look like him (2) it's clearly supposed to be that they immediately go to the flat, (3) it's clearly meant to be that they've been playing Fortnite for a while; he didn't just walk in ahead of them (4) from a narrative perspective, why would you ruin the reveal of survival of Korg and Miek?    I mean, of course we could theorize ways to make it work, but this doesn't pass Occam's Razor in a bunch of ways.